# RMI connection failure detection on callback

Tags: java, rmi

I'm writing a distributed app by Java RMI. The RMI client registers event handler / callback to RMI server, and the server calls the client's callback function when required. Now the problem is, when network connection failure (for example, Ethernet cable plugged out...), the RMI server and client won't be notified, and the RMI server fails when attempts to call the client's registered callback function.The RMI server cannot notify the RMI client about this issue too. Even worse, when network connection recovers, the RMI client service will still lose contact with RMI server because nobody notify her to reconnect.

My current idea is to implement a ping() method in RMI client in separate thread.
This thread could wake up at regular intervals and check on the server.
if failed, then farce to reconnect.

Any other elegant solutions?  Hope you guys can help !

## the interface

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;


public interface MyInterface extends Remote {
    public int RegisterEventHandler(RemoteMyEventHandler eventHandler) throws RemoteException;
    public void unRegisterEventHandler(int eventHandlerId) throws RemoteException;
}
```

## the RMI Server impelementation

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import com.me.MyInterface;

public class MyInterfaceImpl  implements MyInterface {
{
     public void init() {
        try {
            //... initialize RMI server....
            //....
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   @Override
    public int RegisterEventHandler(RemoteMyEventHandler eventHandler)
            throws RemoteException {
        return MyEventHandlerImp.getInstance().addHandler(eventHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void unRegisterEventHandler(int eventHandlerId)
            throws RemoteException {
        MyEventHandlerImp.getInstance().removeHandler(eventHandlerId);
    }   
}

//handler.notifyEventSnap(events);
```

## the RMI Client implementation

```
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.me.MyInterface;

public class MyService implements NotifyHandler{
{
    private MyInterface client;
    private MyEventHandler myEventHandler;

    private void connectToServer() {
        try {
            //...
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(rmiHost, rmiPort);
            client = (MyInterface) registry.lookup(MyCInterface.class.getName());
        } catch (RemoteException er) {

        } catch (NotBoundException en) {

        } catch (Exception en) {

        } 
    }

    private void startService(){
           //Attach my event handler
            if(client != null)
            {
                myEventHandler = new MyEventHandler();
                myEventHandlerId = client.RegisterEventHandler(myEventHandler);

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you need to look at is RMI Timeout [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822695/java-rmi-client-timeout)

Comment: The client doesn't have to 'contact the server to reconnect' after a network outage. The stub remains valid, the server just has to try again.

Comment: @EJP, what do you mean? As I tested, the client has to call 'registry.lookup...' again, otherwise RemoteException will be thrown

Comment: Not unless the server JVM restarts or the server unexports its remote objects. Please provide he stack trace. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

> when network connection failure (for example, Ethernet cable plugged out...), the RMI server and client won't be notified, and the RMI server fails when attempts to call the client's registered callback function.

Err, that *is* the notification to the server. The server just has to note this and try again later.

> The RMI server cannot notify the RMI client about this issue too.

The client doesn't need to know.

> Even worse, when network connection recovers, the RMI client service will still lose contact with RMI server because nobody notify her to reconnect.

The client doesn't have to 'reconnect'. There is no connect or reconnect step in RMI. As long as the client's JVM and remote objects remain up and exported respectively, the stubs at the server remain valid and can continue to be used by the server.

You're solving a non-problem.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. Remote Objects are still valid as long as the JVM is up and the remote objects are exported. The problem I see is that if the JVM goes down or the remote object is unexported the server will get the same exception as a temporary network outage. I do not believe you can distinguish between the two issues so they must be treated the same. If this is ignored then the server will end up tracking remote objects that will never work which is a memory leak. Pinging the clients and removing them after so many failed attempts seems like the only option.

Comment: If the peer goes down and up you will get NoSuchObjectException rather than a connect exception, indicating a stale stub which definitely must be reacquired. If a stub consistently doesn't work of course it must he discarded and re-acquired. But you should allow yourself a couple of retries in case the condition is transient. And I didn't say anything about 'ignoring' anything.

Comment: I made a general statement about ignoring this problem. I'm sure you answered this somewhere above "Your're solving a non-problem."

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be partially implementing a client/server session. This is a token that the server can track to ensure a client is valid. If there is an error while the server is communicating with the client the session should be ended and all references to the client removed.

Your server is already implementing a session with the integer used to unRegisterEventHandler. You should keep track of those integers somewhere like a Map. If the server cannot connect to a client it should simply unregister that client and make the session invalid by removing it from the map. The server should remove all references to the client and not attempt to communicate with the client until a new session is created.

If a client tries to communicate with the server it should get an InvalidException exception from the server. This way the client can attempt to make a new session by calling RegisterEventHandler in the catch block.

I worked on a project that dealt with this problem using a ping like you suggested at https://code.google.com/p/umuc-team-factor/

All client communication with the server was in a looped try catch block like

```
private void getSession() {
    while(isRun()) {
        try {
            if(server == null) {
                Logger.getLogger(JobClient.class.getName()).info("Server is null.");
                setupServer();
            }
            UUID sid = server.getSession(this);
            synchronized (this) {
                id = sid;
            }
            Logger.getLogger(JobClient.class.getName()).info("Session id is " + id);
            return;
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JobClient.class.getName()).info("Could not get session from server: " + ex + ". setting up server.");
            setupServer();
        }
    }
}
```

This try to setup a session with the server until the program is stopped.

All server communication with the client should end the session for the client if there is a RemoteException thrown. c.status() is similar to a ping.

```
List<UUID> endSessions = new ArrayList<UUID>();
for (UUID id : copy.keySet()) {
    ClientCallback c = copy.get(id).client;
    try {
        ClientStatus status = c.status();
        Logger.getLogger(ProcessManager.class.getName()).info("got client status for " + id + ": " + status.getSessionID() + " -" + status.getJobStatus());
        if (status.getSessionID() == null || !status.getSessionID().equals(id)) {
            endSessions.add(id);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        endSessions.add(id);
        Logger.getLogger(ProcessManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
for (UUID id : endSessions) {
    try {
        endSession(id);
    } catch (SessionExpiredException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProcessManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Why* should he session be closed just because of a temporary network condition? TCP doesn't do that; RMI doesn't do that; why should the application?

Comment: It doesn't have to be. My program checked the clients every 15 seconds. It depends how you define temporary. Apache tomcat allows you to define a time limit for sessions. Why not in this app?