# RMI Timeout between Servers but not for Client

Tags: java, timeout, rmi

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822695/java-rmi-client-timeout) question where one of the answer introduce the JVM pameter `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout` . I know that's an obvious/stupid question, but can someone explain me how to set it in details (usually I don't set these JVM parameters).

Anyway, the most important problem would not get resolved: I'm introducing this timeout in a Distributed System since I need it for communication between Servers. In othere words, if a Server1 calls a remote method of  Server2 and the timeout elapses, then the Server2 is considered lost by the Server1. This timeout is shorter than the one used from a Client to consider a Server down.

So I need two different timeouts: one for RMI between Servers and one from Client to Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set it at whichever JVM is going to be the RMI client in the situation, either via the command line or `System.setProperty(),` just like any other system property.

Comment: And supposing that during the test phase I'm working in localhost (so Client and Servers are executed on the same JVM), is it possible to set a parameter (like the on that I cited above) with two different values(again, one from Client to Server, one from Server to Server)?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. The parameter is set on the JVM. You will have separate JVMs for the client and both servers. The issue of two values in a single JVM does not arise.