# nodeJs and jmx (npm: jmx)

Tags: java, node.js, jmx

I have a problem using the jmx nodeJs package to bridge and communicate with a Java application from nodeJs (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/jmx). My code looks like that:

```
var jmx = require('jmx');

var jmxTester = function(host, port) {
  var jmxrmi = 'service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://' + host + ':' + port + '/jmxrmi';
  winston.debug('jmxrmi is: ', jmxrmi);

  var client = jmx.createClient({
    service: jmxrmi
  });

  client.on('error', function (e) {
    winston.silly('Error: JMX at %s:%d', host, port, e);
    client.disconnect();
  });

  client.on('disconnect', function (err) {
    winston.silly('Successfully disconnected from client.');
  });

  client.on('connect', function() {
    winston.silly('Successfully connected to client.');
    client.disconnect();
  });

  client.connect();
}

module.exports = jmxTester;
```

Using it with:

```
var jmxTester = require('jmxTester');

jmxTester('localhost', 20000);
```

runs into several problems, independent of the fact that I have a jmx running on `localhost:2000` or if I do not have anything running.

1. nodemon cannot restart node anymore. It just shows:

   ```
   [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
   ```

   but it doesn't actually restart. It seems like jmx is leaving something unhandled, a resource open or something, so that nodemon cannot be properly close node.
2. I also noticed that when running the app directly with node, I have to send a kill -9, instead of a "normal" kill. If I remove the jmxFun call, everything works fine. So what is wrong with jmx?

Can anyone help me to figure out how to use jmx within nodeJs properly? So that I get a clean connect and disconnect (on error and without any errors).

Here are some sample outputs:

1. with running JMX application on `localhost:2000` (doing two file changes afterwards, no restart happens):

   ```
   2016-08-04T17:20:06.423Z - debug: jmxrmi is: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:2000/jmxrmi
   2016-08-04T17:20:06.433Z - silly: Successfully connected to client.
   2016-08-04T17:20:06.434Z - silly: Successfully disconnected from client.
   [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
   [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
   ```
2. without an running JMX application on `localhost:2000` (doing two file changes afterwards, no restart happens):

   ```
   2016-08-04T17:34:28.384Z - debug: jmxrmi is:  service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:2000/jmxrmi
   2016-08-04T17:34:28.390Z - silly: Error: JMX at localhost:2000 { [Error: Error running static method
   java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
       java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:369)
       at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
       java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
       at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:122)
       at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:205)
       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1955)
       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1922)
       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:287)
       ... 5 more
       [...]
   [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
   [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for my problems, which has two reasons and I'd love to share it with others, that may find this page:

1. The problem has to do with the node java implementation, which is used by the node jmx module. I couldn't find any explanation, but a solution is stated here: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/573. So I added the following to my main.js, so that prior to binding to my `process.on` the java is 'used':

   ```
   var java = require('java');
   java.import("javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory");
   ```
2. The RMI timeouts should be reduced, otherwise node waits for an response (thanks to the sync implementation of node-jmx). Thus, you should:

   ```
   var System = java.import('java.lang.System');
   System.setProperty('sun.rmi.transport.connectionTimeout', '500');
   System.setProperty('sun.rmi.transport.tcp.handshakeTimeout', '500');
   System.setProperty('sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout', '500');
   System.setProperty('sun.rmi.transport.tcp.readTimeout', '500');
   ```

   First tests showed that the value of 500 may be a little to optimistic for some timeouts. Because I get sometimes a timeout even if the JMX is available (thanks to [Java RMI - Client Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822695/java-rmi-client-timeout#))

Hope that helps others!