# Java RMI extremely slow when Server is not running

Tags: java, javafx, rmi

I have a GUI which uses RMI to get the data that has to be visualized. I'm doing server queries with an AnimationTimer, so in the worst case it could be 60 times/sec. When the server is running everything works perfectly. 
However, if I run the client without the server beeing startet, the whole GUI gets really slow. It seems like the attempt to create a connection is the problem that blocks everything else. But I don't know how to solve it.

Another issue that I don't understand is following: When I close the server application via "x" in it's menubar there is still something running. I have to cancel the program a second time (in the Netbeans toolbar) to fully close it.

Following is the code which runs on client side. The getAllSignals()-method is invoked by an AnimationTimer:

```
public static RMI rmiConnect() {
       try{
           Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1099);
           RMI rmi = (RMI) reg.lookup("server");
           return rmi;
       } catch(RemoteException | NotBoundException e){
           System.out.println(e);
           return null;
       }
    }

     public static Map<String, double> getAllSignals() throws RemoteException, IOException {
     try {
          RMI rmi = rmiConnect();
          Map<String, double> signals = rmi.getAllSignals();
          return (Map<String, double>) signals;
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ExceptionsHandling exception = new ExceptionsHandling();
          Map<String, double> list = exception.failedSignalsQuery();
          return list;
      }
 }
```

Comment: This could, as you have already mentioned, be caused by the connection timeout being too large. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822695/java-rmi-client-timeout and check, if this improves the situation

Comment: Thank you for the link @Gernot. Would the code posted there replace my rmiConnect() method or do I have to add it to that method? I copied the code into the method. The GUI responds pretty well now without the server, however, if I start the server it's not connecting anymore.

Comment: You should not execute network code in the GUI thread. You don't need to do the lookup every time you want to call the remote method. And this is not a 'connect' step. Just do the lookup when the program starts.

Comment: @EJP  I already thought that it is pretty unnecessary to ask for a connection every time, if the connection was already successfull. But the example I saw did it like this. How do I have to change my getAllSignals() method in a way it knows that it has a server connection? If I do this correctly, it probably will also solve my initial problem.

Comment: Make the `rmi` variable a member variable, and only look it up if it's null, or there was a failure calling the remote method last time or whatever you want to do about the case when the server isn't running. It won't solve your performance problem: only shifting it to a separate thread will do that; but it will halve the overhead.

Comment: The code from the post describes how to setup your own socket factory (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/socketfactory/) for more information. This should be done only once, when your program starts up. It might also make sense to follows the second answer here (as it uses configuration instead of code). In general I agree with @EJP that the connection to the remove server should only be done once (and another thread could be used to improve the "reactiveness" of the GUI).

Comment: @EJP It obviously solves the problem when I only do the connection test at the start. If I start the server afterwards I need to poll the connection until there is a connection which brings the problem back, that's right. A seperate thread is probably really what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Gernot If I try to import sun.rmi.transport.tcp... I don't have a responseTimeout suggestion. Another problem that I think could happen: What if the server is running but the responseTimeout is to small, so it never connects although the server is running.

Comment: Nobody said anything about importing. These are *system properties* you can set to control various RMI timeouts.