# Does local method call wait for remote return value in java RMI?

Tags: java, synchronization, rmi

I have a question about how local and remote methods cooperate in Java RMI.
Here's the ideal situation:

```
localClass.setValue(server.getValue());
```

Does `localClass.setValue(..)` awaits for the return value from the server or do I have to make sure of it using some sort of synchronization in local?
What happens if the server needs like 5 seconds to execute `getValue()`?

Comment: @RazvanPopovici OK, what 'semaphore of the instance'? Nothing about it in the question whatsover. Those words do not appear anywhere. You're just making all this up. The synchronization the OP is talking about is time-synchronization between the client and the server. Read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.

Arguments are evaluated left to right before the method is called.

So `localClass.setValue()` isn't even called until the parameter value returned by `server.getValue()` is available. So the *client* waits as long as that takes, and *then* calls `localClass.setValue()`. It isn't `setValue()` that does the waiting, it is the stub's call to `server.getValue()`.

You don't have to do anything about it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The **client wait the 5 sec**, if you would like to set a timeout exception you have to do it by yourself like already suggested in **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822695/java-rmi-client-timeout)** question.